# Getting Visual Studio 2010 Profiler working with ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, profiler

I'm trying to profile an [EPiServer](http://world.episerver.com/) (cms) solution using the built in Visual Studio 2010 profiler.

I'm getting the dreaded **VSEnterpriseHelper.axd 500 error** when starting to profile.

> The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. The server may not be running a version of ASP.NET version 2.0 or greater.  Requesting 'http://localhost:17000/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I've manualy added the profiler settings to web.config and added the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.dll to the project.

I can before profiling and even when the 500 error occurs browse to the path `http://localhost:17000/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd` 
and it will return 
`ProcessId=9252;ImpersonatedIdentity=IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool;ProcessIdentity=IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool;CanInstrument=True;IsWin32=False`

I've tried to catch the error using

```
protected void Application_Error(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
    Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
}
```

but it seems the error occurs outside my application because nothing is written to [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

How can I find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late arriving here, but I had this problem for Performance Analysis in Visual Studio 2012.

Viewing the logs in the Event Viewer showed me the exception details - it was an error in .net, and this gave me more information about it and allowed me to isolate the cause.

In my case the error was due to an error with the Cassette Bundling, which is mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette/issues/154):

> Exception type: TinyIoCResolutionException
>
> Exception message: Unable to resolve type: Cassette.Views.BundlesHelper

The resolution for me, as per the January 23rd post by Amethi specifically fixed it for me, was to add the following to the cassette node in the web.config:

```
<cassette cacheDirectory="~/app_data" />
```

Then launching the Performance Analysis tool again showed that it was fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to merge the .config files into web.config, also remove web.config.backup before retrying. Also make sure that web.config isnt write protected.

Comment: I think the OP already tried this, he's already modified his web.config. I've been having the same sort of problem.